# Setting the color of <ActionItem> in NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript

My setup is as follows in my NativeScript Angular2 project:

`<ActionBar>
  <ActionItem text="Select City" color="white"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>`
On Android however, the color of the text is always black. How would I go about applying a color change to these action items?

Comment: did the answer below help or not?

Answer (score 1):

Two options here @arafeek.

- https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/action-bar#styling
- The other option (requires some android work) would be to modify your styles/theme xml files to set the action items to white for the default theme.

Comment: The link is the same than: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/globals, is it suppose to point somewhere else?

Comment: @Brad Martin you should update your link and pointing to the right docs.

Comment: The link takes us no where